# How can I create a new document without opening vim?

Tags: vim, terminal

Is there any way I can create a new vim document without opening vim right away? For instance, when I enter `vim myfile.txt`, I'm launched into vim. I don't want to be launched into vim.

Comment: `touch myfile.txt`

Comment: Directly in a shell: `> myfile.txt`

Comment: ooo, That's definitely a good one, @IngoKarkat. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always use the `touch` command and then edit the file using vim or any of the other editors.

For example `touch myfile.txt` will create a blank file called myfile.txt.

There is no parameter or flag one can use to temporarily suspend the opening of vim when creating a file.

Comment: Ahh... Didn't think of that for some reason. I'm a loser. Thanks. I'll accept your answer when the limiter is gone (I have 10 minutes).

Comment: Not to worry! Everyone has brain farts

Comment: Its funny how sometimes the best answer is the most simple one, and how it can be easy to overlook simple methods like that. Touch was one of the first commands that I learned about when I started college...having previously never used Linux.

Comment: For completeness, under Windows, to create a zero length file: `type nul > myfile.txt`

Answer (score 3):

I/O redirection will also help you. You can create new file by:

```
> newfilename
```

I always use this way because input little, :)

This way has risks. Because `>` means **truncates** file "newfilename" to zero length, if "newfilename" does not exists, then create a new zero-length file.

If the "newfilename" exists, then this command **will "delete" all contents**! Be careful about it.